# creating nxn matrix of special structure in numpy: sum of identity matrix and the same matrix shifted rightward by 1 column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

Given an integer `n` I want to make `n x n` numpy matrices of the following form.

For `n =4`:

```
array([[1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

For `n= 5`:

```
array([[1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

Mathematically, it's adding identity matrix with a matrix which is essentially identity matrix shifted rightward by 1 column. Here is decomposed example.
[image]

How can I do this in `numpy` where the input is `n`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check with `numpy` `roll`

```
n = 3
a1 = np.diag(np.full(n, 1))
out = a1+np.roll(a1,shift=1, axis=1)
out
Out[21]: 
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1]])
```